# Compiler to create an Android app from a WordPress blog

Tags: android, software-development, wordpress

There are a lot of services that simply turns your blog into an app that opens the mobile optimized version inside a browser kind of thing. I'm not looking for such 'converters'.

**Is there any Open Source/Free codebase that I can import into my Android Studio, compile and make an APK that's purely native and not a hybrid app?**

Since WordPress is the most widely used CMS and it has its API, I'm just trying **not to reinvent the wheel** by starting from scratch.

Please guide me, I'm a newbie to Android, but want to build an app myself, rather than falling for these hybrid promises which is nothing but a browser that only opens one site.

Comment: Would [Worona](https://wordpress.org/plugins/worona/) work for you?

Comment: Also - two more to check out, [WordApp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordapp-mobile-app/) & [DroidPress](http://droidpress.com/) - Do any or all three of these work for you?

Comment: 1) Do you want the resulting app to work (content is readable) even when I install the APK on an offline device that has never seen and will never see the Internet? 2) Should the content be somehow kept up-to-date, for instance when you publish a new blog article should it appear in my app?